# Detect keypress over full screen iframe (in this case a twitch embed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, embed, twitch

https://jsfiddle.net/6gf72kb2/

To be clear, I don't care if the keypress does what it's supposed to do on the twitch embed, and I don't want to edit anything on the embed itself or access anything within the embed.  I just want to listen and do something on my own site as a result of the keypress.

I've tried:

```
$('body iframe').load(function() {

        $(document.getElementById('twitchiframe').contentWindow.document).keydown(function(e) {
            alert('hey');
        });            

});
```

That gives the following error:

Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

I also looked at about a million different stack overflow questions to try and figure it out, any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I think this is not possible. The error is due to `CORS`, I have tried adding a listener on the parent div, and the iframe doesnt seem to pass it up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure it's going to be possible, hopefully someone finds a solution.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: I think its definitely impossible unless you want to make a browser extension.